# Creating Package of Bucketed Sitecore Items

Tags: packages, buckets, package-designer

Recently I faced an issue in my project. I have to migrate few Sitecore items from one environment to another by creating package of them. But the issue is that few of the Sitecore items are **Bucketed**. I tried to search on google but could not get a proper solution? So is it possible to create package of Bucketed items. If it is possible, please tell me how it can be achieved. Or is there any other work around of how can I migrate Bucketed items from one instance to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by our Climber, you can create the package just as with normal items.
But if you don't want the entire bucket and have no idea where to look, you could use the "`Items dynamically`" option when inserting items in the Package Designer.

You will be asked for a root item (your bucket) and then there are several options to search for items to include in your package. This can be a regular search, or based on the creation/modification date, ...

After you have set all parameters you can verify the result by clicking on the created "`source`". This will open a new tab in the Package Designer (called Source) and has the option to review your search parameters, set install options, but also to preview the result (which is nice to check if your parameters are correct).

[image]

Remember that if you need to package new items, you probably also need the parent items (in this case the 'invisible' folders created in the bucket)..

Answer (score 1):

You have to create package with bucket items, in the same way like normal items.

[image]

You need to create package with the parent item (the bucket)

You need to choose **Add with Subitems**

[image]

When you open generated zip files you will see all bucketable items serialized.

[image]